# Sorting Google API responses -

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I am using the Google + API to fetch a users' public activities, using the appropriate endpoint.

However, Google returns the activities in no particular order - Here is a snippet:

```
  {
   "kind": "plus#activity",
   "published": "2014-07-31T13:40:41.017Z"
  },
  {
   "kind": "plus#activity",
   "published": "2014-08-27T01:51:25.378Z"
  },
  {
   "kind": "plus#activity",
   "published": "2014-09-05T02:52:33.654Z"
  },
  {
   "kind": "plus#activity",
   "published": "2014-08-12T18:00:59.920Z"
  },
  {
   "kind": "plus#activity",
   "published": "2014-08-14T18:52:00.420Z"
  },
  {
   "kind": "plus#activity",
   "published": "2014-08-01T13:41:10.034Z"
  },
  //[...]
```

So what do I have to pass into the request to get Google to send me the response in order from most recent to oldest? -- or is this something I have to do, myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation and on [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=63&can=1&q=order&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars), I'd say this is not possible at the moment with the `list` method, only with `search`.